# F# Opensource WindowTabs Bug Fix window position

Tags: f#

Opensource WindowTabs is popular project,
there seems to be fork 95.

I want to fix bug.

MultiMonitor(MultiDisplay) environment

```
[1][2]
 [3]
```

Tab Window move and same TabGroup Window shoud hide but not hide Move monitor[3].

I know the location of the code.
However, I have no idea how to modify it.

https://github.com/standard-software/WindowTabs/blob/master/WtProgram/Shared/Win32.fs#L503

```
    member this.hideOffScreen (size:Sz option) =
        let corners = Mon.all.map <| fun monitor -> monitor.workRect.BR.sub(monitor.workRect.location)
        let corner = corners.fold (Pt()) <| fun maxCorner corner ->
            if maxCorner.x < corner.x then maxCorner else corner

        let corner = corners.fold corner <| fun maxCorner corner ->
            if  maxCorner.x = corner.x && 
                maxCorner.y < corner.y then
                maxCorner
            else
                corner
        let corner = Pt(corner.x-1, corner.y-1)
        this.setPlacement({
            this.placement with
            showCmd = ShowWindowCommands.SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE
            rcNormalPosition = Rect(
                corner,
                if size.IsSome then size.Value else this.placement.rcNormalPosition.size
            )
        })
```

I think corner is monitor[1] bottom right position.

I want to do corner is workRect area bottom right .
Then the window hiding feature works fine.

for example : let corner = Pt(corner.x+2000, corner.y+2000)
But it's not cool

I can't use F# for debugging output as it doesn't work at all, but I'm glad if anyone could help.